# Passing an element of a generic array to a generic function

Tags: c, generics, syntax

We have an array with pointers to generic arrays, and an array of generic functions, we want to apply to each element in array `i` the function `i` from `func_ptarrs`.

```
typedef struct genarr{
    void * arr;
    int elemsize;
    int numelem;
}GENARR;

typedef void(*funcptr)(void*);

typedef unsigned char byte;

void updateall(GENARR *arrs, funcptr *func_ptarrs, int n){

    int j,i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < arrs[i].numelem; j++){

            func_ptarrs[i]((arrs[i].((byte*)(arr + j*arrs[i].elemsize)))); //error: expected member name

            //func_ptarrs[i]((arrs[i].arr)); //no error
        }
    }
}
```

In the second try it's pointer to the beginning of the array so it's accepted, but  I need to be able to send each element of the array to the generic function.

I don't understand how to send the right amount of bytes and move correctly in array all while sending pointers of the elements to the generic functions.

Maybe I should use `memcpy`?

Comment: Pass an element from `arrs[i].arr[j]` to function `func_ptarrs[i]` @iharob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this instead,

```
func_ptarrs[i](((byte*) arrs[i].arr + j * arrs[i].elemsize))
```

and I think it's pretty obvious why it would work.

You could write accessor macros too, like

```
#define ARRAY_VALUE(type, x, i (*(type *) ((x).arr + (i) * (x).elemsize))
```

which you can then use like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARRAY_VALUE(type, x, i) (*(type *) ((x).arr + (i) * (x).elemsize))

typedef struct genarr
{
    void * arr;
    int elemsize;
    int numelem;
} GENARR;

int main (void)
{
    GENARR array;
    int    data[10];

    array.arr = data;
    array.elemsize = sizeof(*data);
    array.numelem = sizeof(data) / array.elemsize;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < array.numelem ; ++i)
        ARRAY_VALUE(int, array, i) = i;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < array.numelem ; ++i)
        printf("%d\n", ARRAY_VALUE(int, array, i));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Um there's still an error: expression must be a pointer to a complete object type. It's on `arrs[i].arr`

Comment: @kuhaku Sorry, it was a mistake I just noticed it.

Comment: Can you please explain why it sends the right amount of bytes? How does it know the size without casting?

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you please be more specific?

Comment: We have an element in in the array and its size is `elemsize`, we want to send that element using the above code, what I ask is how does: `((byte*) arrs[i].arr + j * arrs[i].elemsize)` sends `elemsize` bytes to the generic function? Why it isn't more or less than `elemsize` bytes?

Comment: @kuhaku It doesn't send `elemsize` bytes it sends the address to the `j`-th element if all elements are the same size. You can send the size explicitly if you need to. You just send the base address plus an offset, that's all, how it's accessed depends on the cast, so you must be very careful. In my experience I would avoid such construct.